# Neo4j HA failure during 3 node cluster

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Using Neo4j 2.1.8 in HA mode with a 3 node cluster.  During the runtime of the master, the following exception showed up:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.BranchedDataException: The cluster contains two logically different versions of the database.. This will be automatically resolved. Details: I (machineId:1) think machineId for txId (2679) is (1, 173744858547), but master (machineId:2) says that it's HandshakeResult[author:1, checksum:169449888034, epoch:564397954560447]
at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.checkDataConsistencyWithMaster(SwitchToSlave.java:593) [neo4j-ha-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
```

It looks like it tried to recover, but fails as shown below:

```
2015-11-20 06:32:29.009+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.x.NeoStoreXaDataSource]: NeoStore closed
2015-11-20 06:32:29.134+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.TxManager]: TM shutting down
2015-11-20 06:32:33.845+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 212ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:41.755+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Closed log db\data.db\index\lucene.log
2015-11-20 06:32:42.425+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 408ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:48.244+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 534ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:49.118+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 345ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:50.163+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 394ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:51.021+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 335ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:51.879+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 327ms.
2015-11-20 06:32:51.941+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.h.c.SwitchToSlave]: Failed while trying to handle branched data
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils$MaybeWindowsMemoryMappedFileReleaseProblem: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: db\data.db\index\lucene\node\nodeType\_0.fdt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils.deleteFileWithRetries(FileUtils.java:466) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils.deleteFileWithRetries(FileUtils.java:469) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
```

The following is the exception from the master:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Timeout waiting for database to allow new transactions. 1 reasons for blocking: Cluster state is 'TO_SLAVE'.
at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.beginTx(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:218) ~[neo4j-ha-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
```

And this next one is from the slave:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:141) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:112) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at com.genesys.transaction.TxTransaction.finish(TxTransaction.java:103) ~[classes/:na]
... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException: Unable to rollback Transaction[eventId=4519,thread=373:'genesys-msg-4',status=STATUS_ROLLING_BACK,resourceCount=2] ---> error in commit: javax.transaction.xa.XAException ---> error code for rollback: 0
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:530) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:385) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:126) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Unknown xid[GlobalId[NEOKERNL|8441255123473722067|4522|3], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ]]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.rollback(XaResourceManager.java:665) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.rollback(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:111) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doRollback(TransactionImpl.java:581) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:517) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your cluster seems to be in a pretty bad shape. Plus you're on quite old version of Neo4j (there have been eight 2.2.x releases and two 2.3.x ones since your version). You're best off contacting Neo4j's support, I'm assuming you have an enterprise subscription. Anyway, what was the question? How to recover? Do you have backups?

Comment: You are writing to a slave, please configure your load balancer so that writes go to the master.

Comment: You can also drop me an email to michael at neo4j.org